# Bootcamp assistant doesn't show windows partition anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, boot-camp

I want to install Windows 7  back on my Macbook Pro mid 2010 model. But When I run Bootcamp assistant I don't see a Windows partition to resize it, only one big Mac partition.

Here is some screenshots from Disk Utility (I created the Bootcamp partition just now as ExFat):
[image]

And this is what I get in Bootcamp assistant:
[image]

[image]

`diskutil list` command:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            159.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Bootcamp                159.1 GB   disk0s7
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data
```

And this is the results from `gpt show` command:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0
Password:
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=320072933376; sectorsize=512; blocks=625142448
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 625142447
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  312366384      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  312776024    1269544      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  314045568  310834696      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  624880264     262144         
  625142408          7      5  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  625142415         32         Sec GPT table
  625142447          1         Sec GPT header
```

Any idea anyone how can I get back my windows partition so I can install Windows 7 again ?

Answer (score 1):

Boot Camp Assistant doesn't have the capability to resize the Windows partition, just to create or remove it. Since you already have a Windows partition, only the remove function is available.

Comment: so how do i install windows then ?

Comment: What is currently on the Windows ("Bootcamp") partition?

Comment: Nothing, is empty...

Comment: Then use the "remove" function to go back to a single-partition OS X volume, then run Boot Camp Assistant to create a new Windows partition and install Windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is not because Boot Camp can not see the partition - it is presenting to you what the partition scheme will be once you hit continue and it removes Windows. Note the wording in the dialogue, where it says

> "Macintosh HD" will be partitioned **as**

I have been through this process several times, and once you continue it will remove it no problem. It is just presenting the final outcome to you, and it does recognize it being there. Once you go through with this, at the end it will no longer offer the option to `Remove Windows`, if you run the assistant again.

Once you have deleted the existing partition, it will allow you to create a new one again, once you restart the assistant. Boot Camp cannot resize, only remove and create.